# The specified type member 'Organizations' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: sql, linq, model-view-controller

So I took over this project from school that utilizes MVC and I'm learning as I go. One thing the school wanted me to do was to add a new table to the database called Organization. They wanted the Organization to have a foreign key in the User table(AspNetUser) linking it to the Organization table with a primary key, Org_ID, and a organization name, Org_Type.  They want every user to be a part of a specific organization. I've added that table to my database successfully. Now there is a table for the data entry that shows all the inputted data for the scholarshipCredits table. This table can currently be filtered by searching by email, but they want it to be capable of searching by last name or organization as well.  I'm currently trying to get the organization to display in the table. If I change the display information in the View to the foreign key within AspNetUser it'll display correctly in the table but I want the Org_Type to show up. I joined the Organizations table to the linq statement "scholarshipCredits" in Controllers and I thought this would fix the issue but it has not. When I try to sort the column "organizations" it gives me this error: The specified type member 'Organizations' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<L2E_MVC.Models.ScholarshipCredit>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Data Entry";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout - DataEntry.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Search by: </p>
    <p> @Html.RadioButton("searchType", "Email", true) Email </p>
    <p> @Html.RadioButton("searchType", "Organization") Organization</p>
    <p> @Html.RadioButton("searchType", "name") Last Name</p>
    <p>
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Is Spent", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IsSpentSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Email", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.EmailSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Organization", "Index", new {  sortOrder = ViewBag.OrgSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Activity", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ActivitySortParm })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsSpent)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUser.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Organizations.Org_Type)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StemActivity.Activity)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { pk1 = item.StemId, pk2 = item.UserId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { pk1 = item.StemId, pk2 = item.UserId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { pk1 = item.StemId, pk2 = item.UserId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Controller:

```
        private Entities db = new Entities();
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
        {
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "Date_desc" : "Date";
            ViewBag.IsSpentSortParm = sortOrder == "IsSpent" ? "IsSpent_desc" : "IsSpent";
            ViewBag.EmailSortParm = sortOrder == "Email" ? "Email_desc" : "Email";
            ViewBag.ActivitySortParm = sortOrder == "Activity" ? "Activity_desc" : "Activity";
            ViewBag.OrgSortParm = sortOrder == "Organization" ? "Organization_desc" : "Organization";
            var scholarshipCredits = db.ScholarshipCredits.Include(s => s.AspNetUser).Include(s => s.StemActivity).Join(db.Organizations, s => s.AspNetUser.Org_ID, o => o.Org_ID, (s, o) => s);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.Where(s => s.AspNetUser.Email.Contains(searchString));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "Date":
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderBy(s => s.Date);
                    break;
                case "Date_desc":
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date);
                    break;
                case "IsSpent":
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderBy(s => s.IsSpent);
                    break;
                case "IsSpent_desc":
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderByDescending(s => s.IsSpent);
                    break;
                case "Email":
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderBy(s => s.AspNetUser.Email);
                    break;
                case "Email_desc":
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderByDescending(s => s.AspNetUser.Email);
                    break;
                case "Organization":
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderBy(s => s.Organizations.Org_Type);
                    break;
                case "Organization_desc":
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderByDescending(s => s.Organizations.Org_Type);
                    break;
                case "Activity":
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderBy(s => s.StemActivity.Activity);
                    break;
                case "Activity_desc":
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderByDescending(s => s.StemActivity.Activity);
                    break;
                default:
                    scholarshipCredits = scholarshipCredits.OrderBy(s => s.AspNetUser.Email);
                    break;
            }
            return View(scholarshipCredits.ToList());
        }
```

Model:

```
    public partial class ScholarshipCredit
    {
        public int StemId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsSpent { get; set; }
        public static double totalHours { get; set; }
        public static double totalCredits { get; set; }
        public static double spentCredits { get; set; }
        public static double remainingCredits { get; set; }

        public string userEmailSearch { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
        public virtual StemActivity StemActivity { get; set; }
        public virtual Organizations Organizations { get; set; }
    }
```

Entities:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Entities()
            : base("name=Entities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ScholarshipCredit> ScholarshipCredits { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StemActivity> StemActivities { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<C__MigrationHistory> C__MigrationHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Organizations> Organizations { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Don't join to Organizations, just include it. Change `var scholarshipCredits = db.ScholarshipCredits.Include(s => s.AspNetUser).Include(s => s.StemActivity).Join(db.Organizations, s => s.AspNetUser.Org_ID, o => o.Org_ID, (s, o) => s);` to `var scholarshipCredits = db.ScholarshipCredits.Include(s => s.AspNetUser).Include(s => s.StemActivity).Include(s => s.Organizations);`

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try to do this and I go to the page with the table it gives me an error 'A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'l2eDataModel.ScholarshipCredit' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Organizations'.' Which is why I changed to join thinking that was the mistake.I think this happens because I'm combining 4 tables. ScholarshipCredits connected to AspNetUsers and STEMActivity and now to Organizations through the foreign key from AspNetUsers. ScholarshipCredits and Organizations are not directly linked. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: And I can't directly link them because the Organization is going to belong to each individual user.

Comment: Not following. Show your Organizations class. Are you saying it's not 1:M (a ScholarshipCredit can belong to 1 organization, organizations can have many ScholarshipCredits)?

Comment: Also look at the database. Did EF create an Organization table and FK inside ScholarshipCredit?

Comment: So you added the line `public virtual Organizations Organizations { get; set; }` to the scholarshipCredits model rather than EF doing so?  I believe what you want is that on AspNetUser instead, and then you can `.Include` it there like: `.Include(s=>s.AspNetUser.Select(a=>a.Organizations))`

Comment: It appears your "Organizations" is actually a singular entity rather than a collection of "Organization".  Should probably rename that.  Your order would then become `scholarshipCredits.OrderBy(s => s.AspNetUser.Organization.Org_Type);`

Comment: @SteveGreene There is no relationship between Scholarship Credit and Organizations. I manually added the get; set; in the ScholarshipCredit.cs. The relationship is Scholarship Credit has a FK to AspNetUser which has a FK to Organizations. So 1:M AspNetUser:ScholarshipCredit. 1:M Organizations:AspNetUser.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I manually added the line to ScholarshipCredit before I realized that EF automatically updates that. AspNetUser had that line in it but when I try to add the include part I get a syntax error on Select. "'AspNetUser'  does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepted a first argument of type 'AspNetUser' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

When I googled this it said to use 'using System.Linq' so I added that to my AspNetUser.cs but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @RobertMcKee what should I change to change it from a singular entity to a collection?

Comment: Then you should be able to `.Include(s=>s.AspNetUser.Organizations)`.  As for changing your plural Organizations to a singular Organization, just change the name of the Table/Class.  As you can see in your model, you have a `DbSet<Organizations>`, which would indicate (by name) that it's a collection of collections of Organization, which it isn't.  It's just a `DbSet<Organization>`.  When corrected, it should read `public virtual DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }`

Comment: @RobertMcKee SteveGreene Thanks so much for the help. I found out how to get it to work. Instead of adding the organization table to the linq statement I just changed organizations to aspnetuser.organizations inside the switch order and in the table in the .cshtml file.